# log4j not initializes JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, log4j

Trying to use log4j to log to MS SQL server:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MailTest {
  private static Logger lg = Logger.getLogger(MailTest.class);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MailTest test = new MailTest();
      try {

          lg.info("hello");

      } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  }
```

Got exception:

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ERP_IDMS"
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.getConnection(JDBCAppender.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.execute(JDBCAppender.java:215)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.flushBuffer(JDBCAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:186)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
    at tst.MailTest.main(MailTest.java:35)
d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} INFO  MailTest:35 - hello
```

log4j.properties:

```
# Define the root logger with file appender
log4j.rootLogger = debug, sql, stdout
#log4j.rootLogger = error, sql, stdout

# Log for the Hibernate
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL

# ================ Added as part of logging into DB ====================
# Define the jdbc appender
log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.sql.URL="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ERP_IDMS"


# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.sql.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.sql.user=sa
log4j.appender.sql.password=sa

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
#short
log4j.appender.sql.layout.ConversionPattern=INSERT INTO LOGS1 VALUES ('%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS}' ,'%C','%p','%m', '%throwable{short}', '%throwable{800}')
# Define the xml layout for file appender
log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
#=======================================================================

# Direct to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# =============================================================================
```

I have seen many reports on internet regardin JDBC is not initialized. But how to do this in log4j? How to fix this error?

Comment: This question may be stupid, but did you put your dependency in your pom.xml to include your database driver?

Comment: I have added it as external jar file to my Eclipse project

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SQL Server JDBC driver in your classpath ?
If not, see the article for guidance: [Using the JDBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017)